# How to set Key/Value pair to chrome.storage.sync

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am trying something simple with a Chrome Extension, but the documentation I have found is not clear enough regarding the structure of the methods to use the chrome storage. I have the following code (generic) to store and retrieve some values:

```
var value = 561;
var key = "abc";
chrome.storage.sync.set({ [key] : value });

chrome.storage.sync.get(key, ({ result }) => {
  console.log("value received is: " + result); // This does not work, result = undefined
});
```

If I want to retrieve the `key` added to the store, what is wrong with the previous code?

Comment: Take into account that both `chrome.storage.sync.set` and `chrome.storage.sync.get` work asynchronously.

Comment: @IvánNokonoko It does not work in either way. I could set the `get` after a button click and it won't work.

Comment: Remove the braces from `({ result }) =>` to be like `(result) =>` and use comma instead of `+` to display the result in console log. I.e: `console.log("value received is: ", result)`

Comment: @IvánNokonoko, Yes, those extra braces were the problem. Now the values are received normally. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

When using `{ result }` you are extracting `result` from the first parameter being passed.

Should be instead:

```
var value = 561;
var key = "abc";
chrome.storage.sync.set({[key]: value });

chrome.storage.sync.get(key, ({ abc }) => {
  console.log("value received is: " + abc); 
});

// or

chrome.storage.sync.get(key, (result) => {
  console.log("value received is: " + result.abc); 
});
```

TLDR;
In JavaScript, when adding `{ result }` you are extracting that variable from the underlying object in this case, the parameter.

Assuming the object is:

```
const results = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: 3
}
```

You can simplify the parameters to be like:

```
const { a, b ,c } = results
```

which is similar to:

```
const a = results.a
const b = results.b
const c = results.c
```

Since the first argument in your function is now `{ result }`, it is expecting that key to exist in the first argument of that function. But it doesn't, it should be instead`{abc}`

Comment: Your TLDR; is longer than the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

This got me too, I was confused with the key name passed in a variable, this would be your working code:

```
var value = 561;
var key = "abc";
chrome.storage.sync.set({abc: value }, () => { // abc is not a variable, it is the key string
   console.log("saved: " + value);
});

chrome.storage.sync.get([key], ( result ) => { // here you can use a variable to pass the key
   console.log("value received is: " + result.abc); // abc is the key
});
```